# Is is possible to run knnMatch for different images on different threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, image-processing

I match the keypoints of images using knnMatch, and since my match count is usually upwards of 10,000, knnMatch takes a lot of time to run , and I have to do this for every image in the directory, which I'm currently doing using a for loop (each for loop execution takes around 30 minutes if there are around 15 images). Sometimes the program just gets killed. Can I instead use multithreading for knnMatch, so that all images are synchronously matched, and then I choose the highest inlier to stitch with? In that case, how do I store the inlier of each match, since I can't write to the same variable from different threads.

If multithreading isn't a viable option, is there an alternative to speed up what I'm doing?

Comment: Hello. Normally it is possible to substantially increase the performance when using less keypoints to match two images. You're using a lot of keypoints for each image. Why don't you limit the number of keypoints detected in each image?

Comment: Hey, how do I do that? I'm currently using KAZE. Is there a way to limit the number of keypoints?

Comment: "Can I instead use multithreading" -- parallelization is not a magical cure for poor algorithm design, as well as non-trivial topic with many subtle ways to shoot yourself in the foot (what I'm saying is it will take time to learn it, and you should start from simple problems and work your way up). You might get an order of magnitude with expensive hardware, but that won't make your approach much more practical. Focus on optimizing your single thread performance.

Comment: "Sometimes the program just gets killed." -- and why is that? Is it running out of memory? Investigate and fix that first.

Comment: @DanMašek How would you match 15 images any faster? It's common sense that either I need to make do with a slow algorithm, or try multithreading. Maybe I could reduce the keypoints, but that could affect the stitching.

Comment: @Slay Putting aside the fallacy of appeal to intuition, I'm not saying "don't do it at all", just "don't do it yet", for many reasons. a) Optimize the processing of a single image -- 2 min. seems pretty slow. Some options are reduce the input size/working set, use less resource intensive approach (tune params). Measure the effect those changes have, and analyse the results, so you can make informed decisions. Since you haven't shown your code, it's difficult to give specific advise. b) Set concrete goals -- what's an acceptable processing time and the hardware on which this should be achieved?

Comment: c) Understand and fix crashes/resource exhaustion in existing code. Threading will make debugging more difficult, and will be more resource demanding. d) Spend the time and learn multithreading concepts starting from simple examples. It's a complex topic, and there are many gotchas. Adding few complex libraries (OpenCV, Numpy) you're not entirely familiar with (you asked how to resize an image) complicates it further. To explain all this thoroughly enough far exceeds the scope of a single question, and a naive solution is unlikely to give much benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tune the **threshold** of your KAZE detector:

```
cv2.KAZE_create()
```

In this case the detector will have a threshold=0.001 (default value)

```
cv2.KAZE_create(threshold=0.01)
```

In this case the detector will give you less points than using the default value.

---

Another way to increase performance without affecting the results will be reducing the size of the images you are using :)

For example if you want your image to be 100x100:

```
resized_image = cv2.resize(image, (100,100))
```

**Documentation:**
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#void resize(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, Size dsize, double fx, double fy, int interpolation)

Comment: How do I reduce the size of an image in opencv?

Comment: added to the response